# Nginx magento configuration returns 404 but loads html

Tags: nginx, configuration, magento

over the last couple of days I've been undertaking the task of moving our Magento site from shared hosting to a VPS. The VPS is using Nginx with php-fpm.

**Note** Currently we're also having issues with transferring our domain name over thus when I have been attempting to test the VPS I have been using it's ipv4 address.

### The problem

When I vist the server's address within a browser the page's title is "404 Not Found", No css is loaded however the html elements such as links are displayed; when I attempt to access the Magento backend I am redirected to the "Welcome to Nginx" page.

### vhost config

```
server {
# Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
listen 80;
listen 443 default ssl;

server_name 176.126.242.85;## yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

# Specify path to your SSL certificates.
#ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.key;

# Path to the files in which you wish to
# store your access and error logs.
access_log /path/to/your/logs/access_log;
error_log /path/to/your/logs/error_log;

# If the site is accessed via yourdomain.com
# automatically redirect to www.yourdomain.com.
#if ($host = 'yourdomain.com' ) {
#    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://176.126.242.85/$1permanent;
#}

root /var/www/infepos;

location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}

# Deny access to specific directories no one
# in particular needs access to anyways.
location /app/ { deny all; }
location /includes/ { deny all; }
location /lib/ { deny all; }
location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
location /var/ { deny all; }

# Allow only those who have a login name and password
# to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.
location /var/export/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    autoindex on;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files
# such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
location ~ /\. {
 deny all;
     access_log off;
     log_not_found off;
}

# This redirect is added so to use Magentos
# common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

# Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
# to their relevant handler.
location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

# Handle the exectution of .php files.
location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite / /index.php last;
    }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

I am new to using both Magento and Nginx and any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please try the (unaccepted) solution on [this similar question](http://serverfault.com/q/558684/218590)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however unfortunately the solution you suggested didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the error.

The problem was that I had the default vhost with the same server name as my custom vhost